# using REGEXP_REPLACE to make sure a "£" appears before the value?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, regexp-replace

im looking to use REGEXP_REPLACE in APEX to make alter any value that has been put into a field to be replaced wit the same value, but with a "£" sign at the front of it, is this possible?

my column name is "salary"

ps. oracle SQL, THANKS ALOT!

edit: sorry, im ive just started using SQL at uni and i don't really know what im doing. I want to have a column called "salary" and i want to have a constraint and trigger so that when a value static number value entered in the field, 1000 for example, the constraint sees this and the trigger changes it to £1000, similar to what i managed to do with a phone number:

table:

```
contact_no       VARCHAR2(20) 
              CONSTRAINT students_contact_no_chk CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(contact_no, '\(([[:digit:]]{5})\)([[:digit:]]{6})'))
              CONSTRAINT students_contact_no_nn NOT NULL,
```

trigger:

```
:NEW.contact_no := REGEXP_REPLACE(:NEW.contact_no, '[^[:digit:]]', '');
  :NEW.contact_no := REGEXP_REPLACE(:NEW.contact_no,
                   '([[:digit:]]{5})([[:digit:]]{6})', '(\1) \2');
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some examples of what you want to do.  As you've described the problem, `regexp_replace()` doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: i did my best! sorry in advanced

Comment: Hint: || is what you would use to concatenate two strings. What is the datatype of the salary column? If I were you, I wouldn't store the pound sign as part of the salary. I'd either relabel (or comment) the column to indicate salary_in_gbp, making sure it was of NUMBER datatype, or have a separate column indicating the currency of the salary column. That way, you get to keep the salary stored in a number column, meaning you don't have to worry about validating the column to make sure it's actually a number, and you still get to keep the currency info too.

Comment: Displaying the currency symbol in front of the salary would then become a display issue.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it - salary is a number and should be stored as a number - if you store it a a character string then you will not (easily) be able to do things like sorting numerically as it will try to sort it as a string (i.e. alpha-numerically).

When you want to output salary you can do (if you want formatted output):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( salary, 'L99,999,999.00' ) AS salary
FROM   table_name;
```

Which (depending on your `NLS_CURRENCY` settings) will output:

```
SALARY                 
------------------------
          £1,234,567.89
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your example you can always add the pound currency sign at beginning as below "^" denotes beginning of line in regexp_replace

```
-- assuming salary is varchar2 field
-- and it's already verified for digits only
-- if salary is 1234 then it will make it to £1234
:NEW.salary := regexp_replace(:NEW.salary,'^','£');
```